# Is it to code to have two SPST switches to independently power a single load?

Tags: electrical, nec

Hopefully I can get away without drawing this: assume hot splits to two SPST switches and then each go to the load and neutral returns normally such that when both switches are off device is off, when any switch is on the device is on.

Use case:

- SPST 1: toggle switch for manual vent fan control;
- SPST 2: humidistat sensor switch

Question:
What is code on having hot coming from two different switches? At the end of the day, I don't see a hazard to property and if the breaker is disconnected prior to any work, nor do I see one to humans (e.g., no light-bulb fixture to stick fingers in...).
[image]

Comment: Either two switch loops or a single /3 cable can do this but you can't run single wires from source to switch to device and then back on the neutral from another switch.  Your question sounds like trying to avoid a neutral.

Comment: _mumblemumble a picture is worth 1000 words mumblemumble..._ Nothing has to be to scale or professional, but it sure will help (if it accurately depicts what you're trying to do).

Comment: FreeMan, I was in the process as you were posting that.  I don't really need to have two neutrals back to each switch box, but I see no way to avoid it the way that is drawn since I'll be using 14/2 anyway.  So instead of the way it's drawn, there will actually be two neutrals physically there so they might as well be connected.

Comment: Why are you running neutral through the second switch box?

Comment: I'm running 14 ga. NM-B not conduit so I will always have at least 2 conductors plus ground.  If I use 14/3 as suggested, then there will be a second hot going to the second box.

Answer (score 3):

### Your problem is your wiring, not the idea as a whole.

Paralleling two SPST switching devices is fine under the Code. However, the problem is you are routing the wiring in a way that violates the NEC 300.3(B)/310.10(H) restrictions on paralleled or looped wiring paths.  To fix this, you need to route the cables as if you were wiring a 3-way switch, instead of trying to break power off and have the two switch boxes in a parallel topology with the two switched feeds joining back together at the light.

Note that if you're insisting on using /2 cable throughout, that means you'll need to bring power and the light feed both to the humidity sensor location, and have the manual switch on an old-style switch loop from the humidity sensor.

Comment: I have more 14/3 than 14/2 at the moment.  I don't care how it gets done so long as it is right.  Also, it's more complicated than I thought at first because it's a 3-way toggle.  I need a forum to ask this question; this format is no not particularly conducive... i need a drawing to see what you're saying, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you drew, but I don't think you need or want to do it that way.  You just want the functionality right?  You want a humidistat to power the fan with a manual override to force the fan on.

There are ways to wire it correctly, depending on where the power source is and where you want the humidistat to be.  We can't give you an exhaustive list of the many ways to achieve this in this forum, but here is the most typical way:

Power goes to the switch box.  From there, a /3 cable goes to the fan.  One always hot, one switched hot.  The fan has a *built in* humidistat powered by the always hot, and the switched hot bypasses that to force the fan on.

If you have a separate humidistat, you could run it in a switch loop from the switch box (then you don't need a /3) or from the fan (then you still need it).

Addressing your comment elsewhere: You do not need a relay for this.  You just need to understand that every hot needs to have its neutral in the same cable. You can't create loops that run different ways.  Given that, there are various ways to do what you want.  Look up "switch loop" (as suggested above) and distinguish it from actual large loops of wire running different paths.