# How to use one SPST switch and two SPDT switches in 3-way to control single load per NEC

Tags: electrical, switch

A [similar but improperly-worded question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/291192/is-it-to-code-to-have-two-spst-switches-to-independently-power-a-single-load) was asked previously.  I am trying to understand the options for how to do this and **not** whether the specific plan I've outlined is permissible.

I want to power a small 120 VAC load (rated 0.9 A) via two different "switches"* such that the load is powered on when **either or both** "switches"* is on.

1. SPST switch
2. 2 SPDT switches configured in three-way (*considered as a single "switch" above)

The power supply from a single breaker (so everything the same phase) will go to the load first and then to the switches to simplify the wiring, particularly that of the 3-way switch.

What I've drawn here is something that will do what I want, but I don't understand how it relates to the code discussion brought up in the earlier question.  It does not need to be wired this way and I am open to a relay, but I cannot identify a *specific* relay I can actually purchase that will work.

Further, I am very curious how this would be wired if the load was at the end of the circuit instead of at the beginning necessitating neutral to be carried to it somehow.

[image: Updated wiring diagram]

*Everything is 14/2 except for the 14/3 piece at the bottom right with the red conductor.  LN/LH & C denote "load neutral," "load hot," & "common," respectively.  There are two wire nuts in that diagram that are not drawn explicitly.  Solid blue is the white 14 ga. conductor, the blue/black line is a marked white 14 ga. conductor.

Comment: It may not matter, but it would be good to tell us what version of NEC is in effect in your jurisdiction.

Comment: I don't know; it's not going to be inspected... I want to know **why** the relevant code is on it and if there are conflicting versions then I can make an intelligent decision based on the hazards the code addresses.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, you've got four different wires at the left switch, and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: the left SPDT switch has the dashed black to common and the solid red & solid black to the other terminals.  The two blue/black lines are wire-nutted together.

Comment: Suggestion: Draw schematic first, then specific wiring. That will probably answer your question about how to do this as a simple inline switch setup rather the switch loop you've drawn.

Comment: I marked the wire nuts; unfortunately I neglected to label the wires as 14/2 and 14/3.

Comment: There are several ways to do this correctly, and many ways to do it wrong.  The NEC discussion is a big distraction.   It's easy for someone doing what you are doing to fall into certain traps, but let's just find you a good way to do it.  Are your walls all open, are you laying new cable for this end-to-end?

Comment: "Suggestion: Draw schematic first, then specific wiring. That will probably answer your question about how to do this as a simple inline switch setup rather the switch loop you've drawn."  I don't see how this helps me.

Comment: @jay613: Effectively, yes, everything is yet to be wired and I'm punching holes in whatever I want, however I want to understand why code has been brought up when I've previously asked this question, i.e., the theory behind how to parallel the switches.

Comment: If you want to know if your wiring scheme is NEC approved, then it's necessary to know what version of NEC you're on whether it will be inspected or not. At some point, somebody's going to look at it...

Comment: "I want, however I want to understand why code has been brought up" because _YOU_ specifically put it in the question title. Did you not think we'd read that part, too?

Comment: Ok, so i don't really care about any particular version of any particular code.  I just want to know why there is code around paralleling switches, what it is, and what the hazards are.  Why is this information so hard to find?!

Comment: Based on a comment on Jay613's answer, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Maybe you should tell us about what you're trying to solve instead of trying to justify why your non-code compliant solution is OK, except that it's not code compliant and you don't care.

Comment: Working backwards from what you're doing, a relay seems like it would be so much easier. Low voltage rules are simpler all around. Since you are going for 'all or any' they can whatever switches you want, hooked up in parallel, with very thin wire as all it needs to carry is relay current. My local electronics distributor stocks these in a ready to use housing for about $30, and you would pair them with a 24V transformer. https://www.functionaldevices.com/product/rib2401d/ It's the approach I would use if I needed a bunch of switches to control a small load in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

> What I've drawn here is something that will do what I want, but I don't understand how it relates to the code discussion brought up in the earlier question.

That looks fantastic to my eyes. Meets your objectives (the control scheme, using /2 and /3 cable, and works).  Good job.

As for the why's, it's because this method complies with all that Article 300 stuff, *using the cable you already have*.   It does so at the expense of the "neutral on switch loop" rule, but that doesn't apply to an exhaust fan, and could be complied with by using /3 where you are currently using /2.   Switch loops have their advantages.

> Further, I am very curious how this would be wired if the load was at the end of the circuit instead of at the beginning necessitating neutral to be carried to it somehow.

It could, by using /4 cable or smurf+THHN between the switches.  However, you excluded that option in your list of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Code comes into play because with parallel paths of power to the switch (one via the three-way switch circuit, and one via the humidistat) there are more opportunities to create incorrect circuits, and it is less evident to DIY-ers that they have done so.   The guiding principle is that the live and neutral wires making up a circuit must always be in the same cable or conduit.  They cannot make a big loop (actual physical) the way they always do in electrical schematic diagrams.  The loop is electrical, the physical path is parallel and the entire way.

Here is one way to do it.  This uses a /4 cable that you might not want to buy, and there are other ways.  But this shows you how the neutral carrying current to the fan is always in the same cable as the live.

Two junction boxes for the 3-way switches, that also carry an always-live conductor.  That one goes off in a switch loop to the humidistat directly from the fan.

[image]

[Adding]: Also, I just had a closer look at the diagram in your question and I think that works too.   It is to code (only as far as the specific concern I noted above) and it does not require /4 cable.

A thought - another way to achieve what I think you want with less complexity is, rather than use 3 way switches, use two temporary switches (spring loaded or electronic timers). Run power straight to the fan and run three switch loops from there, one to the stat and one to each timer. Then you can turn on the fan from either location and don't worry about turning it off ... at the timeout, control goes back to the stat.

Comment: Could OP use conduit & separate wires to do this, ensuring that all current carrying wires are in the same piece of conduit?

Comment: @FreeMan sure.  Just regard my "/" notation as a conduit with that many wires.  Or regard NM as a soft conduit.   I'm not sure, actually, I understand your question because I know you know that.

Comment: @jay613: perhaps it might be helpful to show an example of an impermissible circuit? 14/4 and conduit would be options on another project but out of scope for this one.
Ultimately, I was looking for a timed solution to the fan for "toilet use," but I was looking at a 3-way toggle and a 3-way timer.  2 SPST timers and 1 SPST humidistat do seem like a cromulent solution.

Comment: There aren't three-way timers.  It wouldn't make sense from either a human factors or product design perspective to have one switch capable of terminating the countdown of another.  If you want something like that go with Alexa.   What I think you want is to start *or extend* purging smells from either location and then forget about it.   Revert to humidistat automatically.

Comment: A non-compliant example would be in your diagram (in the question) instead of putting the fan where you did, put it on the right side connected to the three-way switch and to the humidistat by a /2 cable from each one.  In that case you'd have two neutrals sharing the circuit load via different  physical paths from one live.  Or you could leave one of the neutrals disconnected, creating a similar problem when the other live wire is in use.

Comment: In my (already crumpled up) diagram, as noted by Mannaseh, the switch loop circuit should also be  a /3 to carry a neutral there even if you don't need it right now.  In case in future you decide, for example, to install a Smart humidistat.   In fact, that would be a great solution.   An Alexa humidistat.  "Humidistat, give me a 10 minute boost."

Answer (score 1):

There are three key rules involved:

##### No Paralleling

You can't have two separate cables (or groups of wires - but since this question is based on cables, I'll stick to that for the rest of the answer) providing power to one location. (There are some exceptions, but they don't apply to typical residential branch circuits.) There are two reasons for that: Balanced currents (more below) and potential for overloads.

The balance problems is because all currents in a single cable must match - e.g., hot and neutral. If you parallel by running two hot/neutral cables to two separate switches and then join them together again at the device then there is no guarantee that the neutral current will "know" where to go and so inevitably the load in each cable will not be balanced (one high hot vs. neutral, one low).

As far as overloads, that is actually *not* a real issue here. Typically paralleling is done (or attempted, because it won't pass a proper inspection) in order to, for example, run 40A over two 12 AWG cables. The problem is that if a wire in one cable breaks, particularly neutral (no breaker at all!). In the 40A/12 AWG example, you might have 32A running continuously over two 12 AWG hot wires (OK as long as split close to 50/50) all returning over a single 12 AWG neutral because the other neutral is broken. That is likely to lead to serious problems. So as a general rule paralleling on residential branch circuits is outright forbidden to avoid numerous problems.

##### Balanced Currents

Currents in a cable must be balanced. Basically current running in one direction must match the current in the other direction. Otherwise there can be some serious induction heating problems. Note that old knob & tube solved the problem by having the wires far apart from each other, but that is not a practical option (and likely not code compliant) for new installations for a *lot* of reasons.

Examples include:

- Hot + Neutral
- Hot + Switched Hot (switch loop)
- Hot + Travelers (one of many 3-way configurations)
- Travelers + Switched Hot (another 3-way)
- Travelers + Neutral (another 3-way)
- Hot + Neutral + Travelers (another 3-way, the catch is it needs /4 cable which is less common)

Most of the time this is easy. One place where it gets tricky is with a 3-way switch configuration that includes hot, neutral and 2 travelers. Sometimes the switches and cabling can be reconfigured to avoid that need, but often it can't and then /4 cable (4 wires plus ground) is needed, as explained in another answer.

##### Neutral In Switch Boxes

Most switch boxes require neutral, even if it is not needed right now for the switch or the switched device. This is a relatively new (NEC 2011) requirement, so many older houses do not have neutral in many switch boxes and are grandfathered. But you generally can't add a new switched circuit and not include neutral. That helps a lot for adding smart switches, but it complicates things here, including sometimes forcing use of /4 cable.

Putting that all together, another answer has things *mostly* right, except that it requires /3 cable to the separate (humidistat) switch to provide neutral (the humidistat *might* need neutral anyway, if it requires constant power for its own electronics).

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks.  Though I wonder if the /3 rule applies to a switch loop going to a ceiling or other location not meant for user interaction, for a specific device (eg humidistat) and following manufacturer instructions for that device.    Probably still wise to do it, but I wonder if it's required.

Comment: It isn't "/3 rule". It is "include neutral" rule. Which is often solved by replacing a /2 with a /3 or a /3 with a /4. But as far as whether neutral is needed for a humidistat probably depends on whether it is **human switchable** (like this Leviton https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-In-Wall-Humidity-Sensor-for-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-Control-Switch-1-4-HP-Residential-Grade-Single-Pole-White-R02-DHS05-1LM/324646573 ) or a module that just sits in the ceiling and turns on/off based on humidity level with no human interaction even possible.